# Azure Application Gateway with API as a backend pool is not working

Tags: api, web-services, azure-application-gateway

I have .net core API inside the web app and that web app is backend pool for azure application gateway. while trying to access the web app got below error.

"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

On app GW, health prob for that web app in unhealthy but while access the API as a https://abc.azurewebsites.net/api/values then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we deploy API in Web App Service then apiname.azurewebsites.net does not work give any probes to application gateway and treat unhealthy. API works like xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/values and Application Gateway also know this path. We have to put /api/values in *override backend path* of *http settings*. Same have to do in h*ealth probes.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can first verify if the backend API could access directly without app gateway. Then this error may happen due to the following main reasons:

> - NSG, UDR or Custom DNS is blocking access to backend pool members.
> - Back-end VMs or instances of virtual machine scale set are not responding to the default health probe.
> - Invalid or improper configuration of custom health probes.
> - Azure Application Gateway's back-end pool is not configured or empty.
> - None of the VMs or instances in virtual machine scale set are healthy.
> - Request time-out or connectivity issues with user requests.

Generally, the `Backend healthy` status and details could point it out and show some clues. You could also verify all of the above reasons one by one according to this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502).

Comment: Thanks for the response, all mentioned things are already in place.

Comment: We have figured out the issues. When we deploy API in Web App then http://xxx.azurewebsites.net does not work. it works like http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/values and Application Gateway treat http://xxx.azurewebsites.net as unhealthy.