# Azure Application Gateway with Api AppService without API gateway

Tags: azure, api, azure-application-gateway

How do i use Application gateway with API in Backend pool. Please note we do not want to use API Gateway due to cost and very few APIs. 
I know how to configure Application gateway with WebApp but not sure how I can use it with an Api. Please give me some links/ references where similar design is available.

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks, Joey Cai. I followed your answer. My backend health probe was showing success, however, I had issues testing this via AppGW public Ip address. I used "path-based routing" to successfully implement this. I am not overriding backend path anymore.

Answer (score 2):

When we deploy API in Web App Service then `apiname.azurewebsites.net` does not work give any probes to application gateway and treat unhealthy. API works like `xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/values` and Application Gateway treat `xxx.azurewebsites.net` as unhealthy. We have to put `/api/values` in override backend path of http settings. Same have to do in health probes.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742331/azure-application-gateway-with-api-as-a-backend-pool-is-not-working).